# Solving a quadratic equations with a coefficient with exponent.

Tags: quadratics, factoring

I am refreshing my mind on how to factor quadratic equations (or polynomials) as I have not done so in $2$ years and I am required to do so with the problem I was assigned. With the equation below, the first variable (called the coefficient if I remember correctly) has an exponent.

$$k^3 + 4k + 2$$

How would I be able to factor this even if it's not rational per say?

Comment: Coefficient is the number before the variable. The coefficient of $k^3$ is 1 in your example. And $4$ for $k$. Also, it's not a quadratic function. It's a depressed cubic. Quadratic is a function with the exponent of $2$ while cubic has an exponent of $3$.

Comment: See [cubic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation).

Comment: https://uniteasy.com/post/1287/

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways factor Cubic equations, such as the cubic identities, where:

$1.$ $a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$

$2.$ $a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$

or there is another way, where you use the Factor theorem, that states that if $f(c)=0$ for some c, the $x-c$ is a factor of $f(x)$

The factors of $2: 1,2,-1,-2$

If we substitute $1$ into the equation: $1+4+2 \neq 0$,

If we substitute $-1$ into the equation: $-1-4+2 \neq 0$

If we substitute $-2$ into the equation: $-8-8+2 \neq 0$

And if we substitute $2$ into the equation: $8+8+2 \neq 0$,

Therefore, you simply cannot factorise the equation $k^3+4k+2$.

Hope this helps.